output repeating and non repating digits using regex from s = '1222311'
I am finding it difficult to write regex expression. Need your help in getting expected output.
import re

pattern1=r'(\d)\1{1,}'

s = '1222311'

c=re.finditer(pattern,s)

for i in c:
    print(i.__getitem__(0))

I managed to get repeating digit but not able to get non repeating digit.
How to frame regex to get non repeating digits and repeating digits.
s = '1222311'

Expected output
Repeating digit :  222 , 11
Non Repeating digit : 1,3


Why do you explicitly ask for 1 or more repetitions when you want 0 or more?

Changing your pattern to r'(\d)(\1*)' will select all digits, and group together each set of consecutive digits.  Then with your list of matches, simply sort them based on length:
import re

s = '1222311'

pattern = r'(\d)\1*'

repeating_digits = []
non_repeating_digits = []

# finditer produces the following matches `['1', '222', '3', '11']`
for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    digits = match.group(0)
    if len(digits) > 1:
        repeating_digits.append(digits)
    else:
        non_repeating_digits.append(digits)

print(f"Repeating digit : {' , '.join(repeating_digits)}")
print(f"Non Repeating digit : {' , '.join(non_repeating_digits)}")

Pattern Explanation
(\d) matches any single digit (0 - 9), and is the first capture group.
\1 is a back reference to the first capture group, (\d). It will match whatever was matched by the first capture group, which in this case is a single digit.
Adding the asterisk to the back reference \1* will match the digit from the first capture group when repeated 1 or more times.

: Can you explain this : (\d)(\1*)

Why capture the repeats? Did you intend to use them, maybe with if match[2]:?

@quoraquestion I added a brief explanation for how the pattern works.  I hope that helps.

(\1) isn't really the back reference, \1 is. Still unclear why you added the parentheses to capture it when you're not using it.

@nocomment I added the capture group because I haven't written a regex expression in years (other than find/replace hacking), and the example I found used a capture group.

You can simply use groupby() and get the repeated and non-repeated digits:
from itertools import groupby

print(tuple(''.join(g) for _, g in groupby('1222311')))

Prints
('1', '222', '3', '11')

Measurements
It's much more efficient than regex in this case, especially from space complexity standpoint.
Here is a rough time measurement however:
import re
from itertools import groupby
import timeit


def regex():
    return re.findall(r'(\d)(\1*)', '1222311' * 1000000)


def gb():
    return tuple(''.join(g) for _, g in groupby('1222311' * 1000000))


a = timeit.timeit(regex, number=10)
b = timeit.timeit(gb, number=10)

print(f"{a} v.s {b}")


Prints
16.654602613998577 v.s 13.207541638053954

"much more efficient" - Please share your measurements.

@user24714692 : Thank you for your solution. I need to go with first solution becasue the question was to do with regex. if i not mentioned it as regex then you have win the game with your solution.

This should be the preferred solution, for the sake of simplicity alone.
